# How to upgrade Subversion version for Windows Netbeans

Tags: windows, svn, netbeans, netbeans6.5

I installed Netbeans then I tried to checkout my projects inside Netbeans. During the process Netbeans informed me something about an old client version of subversion, and now I want to upgrade it. But I don't know where the client is, nor how to update it.

BTW I have TortoiseSVN on the same machine and it works fine with the same repository, and as I use svn+ssh protocol, I configured Netbeans to use TortoisePlink.exe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to update your svn from netbeans you will need to go to Tools|Plugin and apply for updates, if you want to use some other SVN client you have installed in your machine you could tell netbeans to use it going to Tool | Options |Miscellaneous | Versioning then select SVN and indicate the folder that netbeans should use as SVN client.

Hope this helps

Comment: I downloaded another svn client, pointed to it, only to found that there are new bugs. So I gave up and I'm sticking to Tortoise.

Comment: You also have to update the NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf file to force it to use your new commandline svn client. See this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943034/netbeans-7-x-and-subversion-1-7-1/7943094#7943094

Answer (score 1):

If it's the Netbeans module you want to upgrade, just go to Tools | Plugins and it will tell you if there are any updates to be applied. Otherwise, if you keep your TortoiseSVN up to date, then you should have the latest client code. If, for any reason, you need a command-line subversion client, you can download the latest and greatest from [here](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/).

If it's something else, please post the specific message you get from Netbeans.