# NetBeans 7.x and Subversion 1.7.1

Tags: svn, netbeans

After upgrading to the latest TortoiseSVN and checking out a repo, NetBeans is complaining about not having the right version of the SVN client. No problem, I downloaded [Win32SVN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn) which is 1.7.0 (tortoise is 1.7.1, but that shouldn't be a problem).

Then, in NetBeans I pointed it to the subversion binary using Tools > Options > Versioning > Subversion. No joy.

Every time I open my project in NB, I get a big scary warning DB telling me that I need to downgrade my repo or upgrade my SVN client.

What steps did I miss? I'm not willing to downgrade my TortoiseSVN, so how do I bring NB up to snuff?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604767/svn-1-7-in-netbeans-7-0

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All that was needed, in addition to the steps I followed, above (installing Win32SVN and pointing NetBeans to the command line client, was to actually tell the IDE to use the command line client rather than the built-in client (which should be updated by Nov 2011, [according to the devs](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Subversion1_7)).

Open up your PogramFiles/NetBeans folder, look for etc/netbeans.conf, and then, on the netbeans_default_options line inside the quotes, add `-J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline`. This tells NetBeans to use the command line SVN rather than the plugin.

Comment: Cool, that was it - I'm on OS X and did the same thing. The file to edit is /Applications/NetBeans\ 7.0.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf. I'm not sure how (if) this relates to the setting inside Netbeans Settings... > Miscellaneous > Versioning > Subversion tab, but I've also set the path there to where my actual svn installation resides.

Comment: Thank you, this was a life saver!  I was going crazy trying to figure out why changes in TortioiseSVN and NetBeans weren't in sync!

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me:

A relatively official workaround is given here, but note that it already says that the SVN support in NB won’t work fully, because their command line SVN module is crusty.
http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Subversion1_7

Steps I used successfully on Win 7 Pro 64b, NB 7.0.1:
1.  Got and installed the Collabnet 1.7.2 SVN Client (command line stuff)

1. Made sure that the new svn client is on the path (type “svn help” at commandline, and look at the version number near top), 
   (or perhaps you could make sure that that the path to the svn client is explicitly given in NB – Tools – Options – Misc – Versioning – SVN)
2. Edit the netbeans.config file to add the new default option as listed in the article linked above.
3. Now my NB doesn’t complain on startup, but I don’t trust that SVN in NB 7.0.1 works fully, per disclaimers in that article, so I still plan to use TortoiseSVN anyway!