# SVN 1.7+ in Netbeans 7.0

Tags: svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn

I have a project that uses totoiseSVN. Before upgrading it to 1.7 version all works fine, but when I upgrade tortoiseSVN to 1.7 version it gives me an error when I try to commit or to show history log or to update:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Unsupported working copy format
The path 'C:\Users\user\stuff\myApp' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

As I know if my system has toriseSVN installed Netbeans uses it by default. Also I have read that `.svn` directory is located **only** in the root(as in my case) of project(working copy) in svn 1.7+. So why netbeans tells me that I have to upgrade the svn client as I already have the newest version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943034/netbeans-7-x-and-subversion-1-7-1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enable Command line switch in your application shortcut/execution path:

```
-J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline
```

**Example**

```
“C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0.1\bin\netbeans.exe” -J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting `-J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline` option and including svn executable in your `PATH` system variable is enough to solve this problem.

You can set the option by doing this in a way described by tpae OR by adding this option to `netbeans_default_options` property in `<netbeans_dir>\etc\netbeans.conf` file.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans uses the command line client. You still have an 1.6.x version of the command line client somewhere in your PATH env variable.

Comment: I have only tortoise's bin folder in the path