# NetBeans SVN: "Show Annotations" doesn't work

Tags: svn, netbeans

When I try to do Team | Show Annotations it get's "stuck"... The progress bar will show "Annotating...", and the left hand side of the file, where the annotations should show up says "Computing..." These will be stuck until I do "Hide annotations" or i manually cancel the task.

This problem appeared when I changed from svn 1.6.x to 1.7.x (I think), but that was a few months ago so I don't remember clearly.

I'm running Netbeans 7.1.1, java 1.7.05 64bit, TortoiseSVN 1.7.7, windows 7.

I've tried against two different repos with different server version.

Any ideas? I'd rather not change back to running svn 1.6 again...

Edit: I've tried Netbeans 7.2 too, same problem.

Comment: Doesn't this post help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943034/netbeans-7-x-and-subversion-1-7-1?rq=1

Comment: That got me in the right direction, thanks! :)

Comment: Could you vote the comment up then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading [NetBeans 7.x and Subversion 1.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943034/netbeans-7-x-and-subversion-1-7-1) and the answers I realized that under NB-Tools-Misc-Versioning-SVN-Path I had nothing entered, so after putting in C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/ everything worked.

I didn't think about it would matter, since other svn commands seemed to work with nothing in that path? Update for example? And history? Strange. But now it works! :)

Comment: It's not a mandatory field. Usually subversion uses the internal java lib, but I think it's not compatible with svn 1.7.*, so using the command line command works.

Comment: I tried commandline first, with the switch -J-DsvnClientAdapterFactory=commandline. That did not work, then I tried putting in the path = works. Tried it without commandline switch and only path, still works.