# How to work with SVN in Netbeans on Debian?

Tags: svn, netbeans, debian, netbeans-7

I changed my desktop from Xubuntu to Debian. I have Debian Wheezy with an Xfce desktop and NetBeans 7.3. (It was a fresh Squeeze install, but it didn't support my monitors, so I did a dist-upgrade at once.)

The problem I'm facing is that Subversion in NetBeans always throws me authentication errors regardless of the settings I use. Eclipse works fine. Command line SVN works fine. SvnKit is installed, JavaHL is installed. While I used Xubuntu I think it worked out of the box.

I think the problem might be somewhat related to the fact that NetBeans seems to want to use gnome-keyring but I don't have Gnome installed (and I would prefer to keep that so).

What could be the problem and how could I circumvent it?

**EDIT**: I tried [the way described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943034/netbeans-7-x-and-subversion-1-7-1) to hack my NetBeans install to use the command line SVN, but if it's hacked together this way the SSH tunnelling needs needs a private key. The server I have to use supports only user name/password authentication, so I had no luck.

Comment: Distros and Desktops are not the same thing.  If you like your old desktop, you can install it on your current favorite distro.  Just a nit-pick, but it's better to hear it from a sympathetic ear than a few of the very excited to point this out people out there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing command line svn executables (I believe it is in the dep called subversion).  If you can't checkout on the command line, then you probably *really are* passing in the wrong password; however, there *might* be a version compatibility issue.  If so, might investigate installing an older or newer subversion to match the server (the only real solution if you don't have control over you server) or the *much better solution* of upgrading the svn server.

Comment: Perhaps a corrupted copy of NetBeans.  Or maybe a packaging issue (very unlikely, but possible).  Try downloading the new 7.3 directly from netbeans, once expanded put the directory in your home directory and make a ~/bin/ link to the ~/netbeans-version/bin/netbeans command.  Verify the ${HOME}/bin/netbeans is what you will call with `which netbeans` and then give that copy a try.

Comment: Debian Wheezy doesn't have NetBeans 7.3, I downloaded it from netbeans.org